# Add blank column using awk or sed

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

I have a file with the following structure (comma delimited)

```
116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98
```

I want to add a blank column on the 4th field such that it becomes

```
116,1,89458180,,17,FFFF,0403254F98
```

Any inputs as to how to do this using awk or sed if possible ?

thank you

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that none of the fields contain embedded commas, you can restate the task as replacing the third comma with two commas. This is just:

```
sed 's/,/,,/3'
```

With the example line from the file:

```
$ echo "116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98" | sed 's/,/,,/3'
116,1,89458180,,17,FFFF,0403254F98
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use this `awk`,

```
awk -F, '$4="," $4' OFS=, yourfile
```

(OR)

```
awk -F, '$4=FS$4' OFS=, yourfile
```

If you want to add 6th and 8th field,

```
awk -F, '{$4=FS$4; $1=FS$1; $6=FS$6}1' OFS=, yourfile
```

Comment: You could use this `awk -F, '$4=FS$4' OFS=, file`

Comment: How about if I want to add more blank records? For example, I want to add 6th and 8th field?

Comment: @user3003001 did you want to add `,` on 6th and 8th field?

Answer (score 2):

**Through awk**

```
$ echo '116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98' | awk -F, -v OFS="," '{print $1,$2,$3,","$4,$5,$6}'
116,1,89458180,,17,FFFF,0403254F98
```

- It prints a `,` after third field(delimited) by `,`

**Through GNU sed**

```
$ echo 116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98| sed -r 's/^([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*)(.*)$/\1,\2/'
116,1,89458180,,17,FFFF,0403254F98
```

- It captures all the characters upto the third command and stored it into a group. Characters including the third `,` upto the last are stored into another group. In the replacement part, we just add an `,` between these two captured groups.
  Through Basic sed,

**Through Basic sed**

```
$ echo 116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98| sed 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,[^,]*\)\(.*\)$/\1,\2/'
116,1,89458180,,17,FFFF,0403254F98
```

Comment: I would like to write a similar command with `awk`. But I have no idea on number of columns present in the file. How to address the awk command to point till the last column ?

Answer (score 0):

`echo 116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98|awk -F',' '{print $1","$2","$3",,"$4","$5","$6}'`

Answer (score 0):

Non-awk

```
t="116,1,89458180,17,FFFF,0403254F98"
echo $(echo $t|cut -d, -f1-3),,$(echo $t|cut -d, -f4-)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use bellow awk command to achieve that.Replace the  $3 with what ever the column that you want to make it blank.

awk -F, '{$3="" FS $3;}1' OFS=, filename

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -e 's/\([^,]*,\)\{4\}/&,/' YourFile
```

replace the sequence of 4 [content (non comma) than comma ] by itself followed by a comma